# What is letter p in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is a MySQL statement generated by MySQL Query Browser

> SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name p;

I want to know know what is the letter p for in this SQL statement?

Comment: Your question title should be how to use table alias ...... Because letter -p meaning mysql password ;)

Comment: @PiyushGupta no, it not command line from shell, it is a SQL statement in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to use a table name alias.  They're generally used when joining tables together.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html for more info.

You can also use the AS keyword for more clarity:

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name AS p
```

It allows you to specify the table to select columns from when getting data from multiple tables:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee AS t1 INNER JOIN info AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an alias for the table. It's pointless in the example you gave. In a more complex query, it would let you refer to the table as `p` instead of by its name.

See [the table reference syntax in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

For what it's worth, I usually use the optional `AS` syntax (`SELECT * FROM table_name AS P`) to make it more obvious to the (human) reader what's happening.

An example of a query where this would be more useful:

```
SELECT parent.name, child.name
FROM people child
    LEFT JOIN relationships r ON child.id = r.child_id
    LEFT JOIN people parent ON parent.id = r.parent_id
```

Comment: Do you have a better example for this?

Comment: @DotKu as in a more complex query? You'd need to use more than one table to make the alias useful.

Comment: @DotKu I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an alias of long table name `database_name.table_name`. Alias are very convenient when writing complex queries specially joins and save you a lot of typings.

See more information [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)